# Lua - find/match information returned via html source and create new variables

Tags: lua

I'm trying to extract the status of 4 plug sockets via the html source code of the device, which is returned by a http.request.

The values i needed are recorded against the `<script> var sockstates =` e.g [1,0,1,0] ` but it can be anything 1/0 for each below.

I've created the following script as an example to try try and work it through, but I'm not able to extract the 4 values that are reported between the square brackets `[1,1,1,1]`

Any help on how i can focus in on that section and extract the values, would be appreciated.

```
local responseBody = [[ Example source code returned via http.request - <title>EnerGenie LAN Power Manager</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="s.css" />

<script>var sockstates = [1,1,1,1];var mac= "C58A6B4AACE2";var ipid = 0;var serv = 0;var trycon = 0;var active = 0;var actbtn = 1;var warn = 0;var timer= null;var period = 3000;
</script>]]

local socket1, socket2, socket3, socket4 = responseBody:match("(.-)<script>var sockstates = [(%d),(%d),(%d),(%d)];var mac=")

print(socket1, socket2, socket3, socket4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `]` are magic characters used to define a character class. If you want to match them literally you need to escape them using `%`.

```
responseBody:match("(.-)<script>var sockstates = %[(%d),(%d),(%d),(%d)%];var mac=")
```

delivers the expectec result. Just notice that you have 5 captures. The 4 values in square brackets are captures 2-5. You print 1-4.

Comment: Thanks @piglet, sorry for any confusion I only need the 4 socket values, I had tried various things to see if I could get it to work and just posted my last attempt..